# POST Invoices without having the contact ID of this new customer

Tags: php, xero-api

We would like to post / create an invoice for a non existing contact.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices#post

Can you create instant an invoice for a new contact. So if you don't have the contactID value?
If this is possible how to you need add the name in this same post?

Best, Derk

Comment: Have you tried asking on the forum - https://community.xero.com/developer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a contact on-the-fly by POSTing an invoice; you need to supply (at least) the contact name field, and exclude the ContactID field.

You can use the previewer application to try this out - go here, log in with your Xero details, and click "Insert Minimum Xml":

https://app.xero.com/Preview/invoices/POST